# Ant - copy only file not directory

Tags: ant

I need to copy all files in a folder except directory in that folder using Ant script.

Im using below script to do that.

```
<copy todir="targetsir">
  <fileset dir="srcdir">
     <include name="**/*.*"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

But it copies all files and directory in that folder.

how to restrict/filter directory in that folder?

thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean that `srcdir` conatins sub-directories, and you you don't want to copy them, you just want to copy the files one level beneath `srcdir`?

```
<copy todir="targetsir">
  <fileset dir="srcdir">
     <include name="*"/>
     <type type="file"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

That should work. The "`**/*.*`" in your question means "every file under every sub directory". Just using "`*`" will just match the files under srcdir, not subdirectories.

*Edited to exclude creation of empty subdirectories.*

Comment: The * by itself creates empty sub-directories. I would not consider that to be expected behaviour. I would consider @Pavel's solution below to be the right one.

Answer (score 25):

I think there is an easier way.

`flatten="true"` - Ignore directory structure of source directory, copy all files into a single directory, specified by the todir attribute. The default is `false`.

Comment: This question was very difficult to put into words.  Your answer was right on the ant page staring back at me.  Thanks kindly for this!

Answer (score 7):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I'm writing new post here. Both solutions to include `name="*"` or `name="*.*"` work fine in general, but none of them is exactly what you might expect.

The first creates empty directories that are present in the source directory, since `*` matches the directory name as well. `*.*` works mostly because a convention that files have extension and directories not, but if you name your directory `my.dir`, this wildcard will create an empty directory with this name as well.

To do it properly, you can leverage the `<type />` selector that `<fileset />` accepts:

```
<copy todir="targetsir"> 
  <fileset dir="srcdir"> 
     <include name="*"/> 
     <type type="file"/>
  </fileset> 
</copy>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
<copy todir="targetsir"> 
  <fileset dir="srcdir"> 
     <include name="*.*"/> 
  </fileset> 
</copy>
```

** is used to match a directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
<copy todir="targetsir" includeEmptyDirs="false"> 
  <fileset dir="srcdir"> 
     <include name="*"/> 
  </fileset> 
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your folder has many subdirectories and you don't want them to be copied (if you want only files) try this..

```
<target name="copy">
<copy todir="out" flatten="true">
<fileset dir="tn">
<filename name="**/cit.txt" />
</fileset>
</copy>
</target>
```

Comment: By default flatten is set to "false"

Answer (score -1):

The secret is to use not fileset but dirset instead.

Comment: I suspect being more explicit about what you mean here would be beneficial